# gcloud can only create instances using private image

Tags: google-cloud-platform, gcloud

I have a private image called 'test-1' and I can use it to create an instance

```
$ gcloud compute instances create demo --image test-1
```

However I cannot use a public image:

```
$ gcloud compute instances create demo --image ubuntu-1804-bionic-v20190204 
ERROR: (gcloud.compute.instances.create) Could not fetch resource:
 - Invalid value for field 'resource.disks[0].initializeParams.sourceImage': 'https://www.googleapis.com/compute/v1/projects/szabgab-149/global/images/ubuntu-1804-bionic-v20190204'. The referenced image resource cannot be found.
```

Nor a public image family:

```
$ gcloud compute instances create demo --image-family ubuntu-1804-lts 
ERROR: (gcloud.compute.instances.create) Could not fetch resource:
 - The resource 'projects/szabgab-149/global/images/family/ubuntu-1804-lts' was not found
```

What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I've noticed that in the generated error message, that you are generating the location of the image as if it is located in your project, which I understand it is named `szabgab-149`:

> The resource
>   'projects/**szabgab-149**/global/images/family/ubuntu-1804-lts'

The thing is that public images are located in its own projects, see the output of the command [`gcloud compute images list`](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/compute/images/list).

For example, the `ubuntu-1804-bionic-v20190204` is under the project `ubuntu-os-cloud` and the image family `ubuntu-1804-lts`.

To solve this, you can simply add the `--image-project` flag, from the information of the previous gcloud command, you execute this command, to use this specific image:

```
gcloud compute instances create demo \
--image ubuntu-1804-bionic-v20190204 \
--image-project ubuntu-os-cloud
```

Or this one, to use the default image under the project `ubuntu-os-cloud` and family `ubuntu-1804-lts`:

```
gcloud compute instances create demo \
--image-family ubuntu-1804-lts \
--image-project ubuntu-os-cloud
```

Comment: Oh Thanks. This gave me the direction though it was not the exact right solution though. You need to use --image-project ubuntu-os-cloud   (as I understand ---porject is used to indicate where you want to put the the instance). I've edited your answer to use that flag.

Answer (score 0):

```
https://github.com/khushbuparakh/gcp/blob/master/instance.py
```

You can use this. It creates a bucket. Upload your private file to the bucket. Create an image using that file and spin up an instance